# Dynamically populate Text Fields in Flash (AS3)

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, dynamic-text

I am trying to figure out how to dynamically populate textfields in Flash. The text in the fields will either say ON or OFF based on the value of `bstatus`.

`var bstatus` will either have a value of 0 or 1

I have the following textfields listed below.
I'm not sure if the syntax is correct, but I was thinking that the text fields would be in an array, and I would create a for loop--that will go through the array in order to have the fields populated.

```
   var textFields:Array = new Array();
   textFields[0] = compTxt.text;
   textFields[1] = bathLightTxt.text;
   textFields[2] = computerLightTxt.text;
   textFields[3] = kitchenLight.text;
   textFields[4] = livingLightTxt.text;
   textFields[5] = descLightTxt.text;
   textFields[6] = laundryLightTxt.text;
   textFields[3] = ovenTxt.text;
   textFields[8] = tvTxt.text; 
   textFields[9] = washerTxt.text;
```

I'm thinking that that the textFields Array will go inside a function called populateFields()

```
 // function populateFields ------------------------------------------------------------------
  function populateFields(bstatus:int)
{

   var displayText:String="";   

   var textFields:Array = new Array();
   textFields[0] = compTxt.text;
   textFields[1] = bathLightTxt.text;
   textFields[2] = computerLightTxt.text;
   textFields[3] = kitchenLight.text;
   textFields[4] = livingLightTxt.text;
   textFields[5] = descLightTxt.text;
   textFields[6] = laundryLightTxt.text;
   textFields[3] = ovenTxt.text;
   textFields[8] = tvTxt.text; 
   textFields[9] = washerTxt.text; 


  if (bstatus == 0) {
   // textfield will say OFF
          displayText = "OFF";

  } else if (bstatus == 1) {
  // textfield will say ON
            displayText = "ON";

     }


  /*
   for (var i:int=0;i<textFields.length;i++)
   {
                      // do something

   }
  */


}
```

Entire Code:

```
package {

        import flash.display.MovieClip;
         import flash.events.MouseEvent;
         import flash.events.Event;
      import flash.events.EventDispatcher; //event dispatcher

     public class House extends MovieClip

     {
     // List Objects inside Treehouse here....
        //private var comp:MovieClip; // comp is a property of TreeHouse
     //private var light:MovieClip;
     //var comp:HouseObjects = new HouseObjects(); //do this inside another class


     var HouseObjects:Array = new Array(); // creates HouseObjects array
     var onList:Array = [];

     var obj_num:int = 10;

     var power:int; // holds value of individual House Objects
     var bstate:int; // 0 or 1 (ON or OFF)
     var bstatus:int;
        var userInput:int; // stores user data (of selected data); holds value of e.currentTarget.power
     var currentPower:int; // stores current power
     //var objName:String;
     var objSelect:Object;

     // Constructor--------------------------------------------------------------------
     public function House()


     {
      var currentPower:int = 0;

      HouseObjects[0] = new Comp();
      HouseObjects[1] = new Light(); // bathroom light
      HouseObjects[2] = new LightB(); // computer area light
      HouseObjects[3] = new LightC(); // kitchen light
      HouseObjects[4] = new LightD(); // living room light
      HouseObjects[5] = new LightE(); // description light
      HouseObjects[6] = new LightF(); // laundry room light
      HouseObjects[7] = new Oven();
      HouseObjects[8] = new Tv();
      HouseObjects[9] = new Washer();
      //HouseObjects[10] = new Car();

      //onList.push(objName);
      //trace(objName);

      //onList.push(HouseObjects[1]);
      trace("Tracing onList Array: " + onList);

      // list properties of the objects -----------------------------------------------------------------
      HouseObjects[0].power = 2; // amount of power
      HouseObjects[0].name = "comp";
      //comp.bstate = 0; // button state

      HouseObjects[1].power = 1; // amount of power
      HouseObjects[1].name = "light"; 

      HouseObjects[2].power = 1; // amount of power
      HouseObjects[2].name = "lightB"; 

      HouseObjects[3].power = 1; // amount of power
      HouseObjects[3].name = "lightC";

      HouseObjects[4].power = 1; // amount of power
      HouseObjects[4].name = "lightD";

      HouseObjects[5].power = 1; // amount of power
      HouseObjects[5].name = "lightE";

      HouseObjects[6].power = 1; // amount of power
      HouseObjects[6].name = "lightF";

      HouseObjects[7].power = 3; // amount of power
      HouseObjects[7].name = "oven"; 

      HouseObjects[8].power = 4; // amount of power
      HouseObjects[8].name = "tv"; 

      HouseObjects[9].power = 5; // amount of power
      HouseObjects[9].name = "washer"; 

      //HouseObjects[9].power = 6; // amount of power
      //HouseObjects[9].name = "car";
       // end of list properties of the house objects -----------------------------------------------------



      for (var i:int=0;i<obj_num;i++)
      {

      HouseObjects[i].buttonMode = true;

      //add event listeners -- listens to functions that are called  
        HouseObjects[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, rolloverToggle);
        HouseObjects[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, rolloutToggle);
        HouseObjects[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, toggleClick);
        HouseObjects[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, toggleClick);
        HouseObjects[i].bstate = 0;

       stage.addChild(HouseObjects[i]); // add House Objects to stage ------------------------------

        }// end of for loop ------------------------------------------------------------------------

       trace("tracing...");
       //computer's position
       HouseObjects[0].x = 585;
       HouseObjects[0].y = 233;

       //bathroom light's position
       HouseObjects[1].x = 340;
       HouseObjects[1].y = 161;

      //computer lightB's position
       HouseObjects[2].x = 579;
       HouseObjects[2].y = 158;

       //computer lightC's position
       HouseObjects[3].x = 316;
       HouseObjects[3].y = 368;

       //computer lightD's position
       HouseObjects[4].x = 657;
       HouseObjects[4].y = 367;

       //computer lightE's position
       HouseObjects[5].x = 517;
       HouseObjects[5].y = 549;

       //computer lightF's position
       HouseObjects[6].x = 531;
       HouseObjects[6].y = 1000;

       //oven's position
       HouseObjects[7].x = 380;
       HouseObjects[7].y = 449;

       //tv's position
       HouseObjects[8].x = 543;
       HouseObjects[8].y = 423; 

       //washer's position
       HouseObjects[9].x = 637;
       HouseObjects[9].y = 1155; 

     } // end of Constructor -----------------------------------------------------------

     // function rollOver -------------------------------------------------------------- 
     function rolloverToggle(e:MouseEvent) {  
      if (e.currentTarget.currentFrame == 1)
      e.currentTarget.gotoAndStop(2);
        if (e.currentTarget.currentFrame == 3)
      e.currentTarget.gotoAndStop(4);
     }

     // function rollOut ----------------------------------------------------------------- 
     function rolloutToggle(e:MouseEvent) {
      if (e.currentTarget.currentFrame == 2)
      e.currentTarget.gotoAndStop(1);
      if (e.currentTarget.currentFrame == 4)
      e.currentTarget.gotoAndStop(3); 
     }

     // function toggleClick-------------------------------------------------------------
       function toggleClick(e:MouseEvent) {

       // On MouseEvent gotoAndStop(Frame Number)
       if (e.currentTarget.currentFrame == 2)
        {
      e.currentTarget.gotoAndStop(3);
      e.currentTarget.bstate = 1;
        }

        if (e.currentTarget.currentFrame == 4)
        {
      e.currentTarget.gotoAndStop(1);
      e.currentTarget.bstate = 0;
        }  

       // trace statements -------------------------------------------------------
       //trace("movieClip Instance Name = " + e.currentTarget); // [object Comp]
       //trace(houseArray[e.currentTarget.name]); // comp
       trace("using currentTarget: " + e.currentTarget.name); // comp
       //trace("powerData: " + powerData); // power of user data
       //trace("houseArray: " + houseArray[0]); // the 0 index of house array
      // trace(e.currentTarget.power); // currentTarget's power************
       //trace ("bstate in click function: " + e.currentTarget.bstate);
       //objName = e.currentTarget.name;


       trace("target: " + e.currentTarget);

       bstatus = e.currentTarget.bstate;
       userInput = e.currentTarget.power;
       objSelect = e.currentTarget;
       trace("objSelect: " + objSelect);
      // end of trace statements -------------------------------------------------

       calcPower(userInput, bstatus);
       //trace("i am bstatus: " + bstatus);
       //trace("i am power: " + userInput);

       populateFields(bstatus);

       sendPhp();

       //trackItems(objSelect, bstatus);

       } // end of function toggleClick ----------------------------------------------------

    // function calcPower ------------------------------------------------------------------
     function calcPower(userInput:int, bstatus:int):void 
     {
      //trace("i arrived");
      //trace("power: " + userInput + " and " + "bstate: " + bstatus);
      if (bstatus == 0) {
       trace("i have been clicked OFF");
         currentPower -= userInput; // if OFF then minus
      trace("currentPower: " + currentPower);

      } else if (bstatus == 1) {
       trace("i have been clicked ON");
         currentPower += userInput; // if OFF then minus
      trace("currentPower: " + currentPower);
      }  

     }

     // function populateFields ------------------------------------------------------------------
      function populateFields(bstatus:int)
    {

       var displayText:String="";



       var textFields:Array = new Array();
       textFields[0] = compTxt.text;
       textFields[1] = bathLightTxt.text;
       textFields[2] = computerLightTxt.text;
       textFields[3] = kitchenLight.text;
       textFields[4] = livingLightTxt.text;
       textFields[5] = descLightTxt.text;
       textFields[6] = laundryLightTxt.text;
       textFields[3] = ovenTxt.text;
       textFields[8] = tvTxt.text; 
       textFields[9] = WasherTxt.text; 


      if (bstatus == 0) {
       // textfield will say OFF

      } else if (bstatus == 1) {
      // textfield will say ON
      }


      /*
       for (var i:int=0;i<textFields.length;i++)
       {
                          // do something

       }
      */

    }

     // function pwrPercentage ------------------------------------------------------------------
      /*function pwrPercentage()
    {
    }
     */

     // function trackItems ------------------------------------------------------------------
      function trackItems(objSelect:Object, bstatus:int):void 
     {
      trace("i arrived in trackItems");
      trace("tracing objSelect in function trackItems: " + objSelect);
      //trace("tracing Array onList :" + onList);
      //trace("power: " + userInput + " and " + "bstate: " + bstatus);
      if (bstatus == 0) {
       //onList.removeItemAt(onList.getItemIndex(objSelect));
      // remove from ON list (array) pop

      // call function removeArrayItem
      removeArrayItem(objSelect);    

      } else if (bstatus == 1) {
       //trace("adding items to list");
      onList.push(objSelect);
      //add to ON list (array) push  
      }  
      trace("Array:" + onList);
      //return array .... only have one array...contain objects that are ONLY ON  
     }

    // function removeArrayItem ------------------------------------------------------------------ 
     function removeArrayItem(objSelect:Object):void
    {
      var arrayLength:int = onList.length;

      // Searches item in array
      for (var i:int=0; i<arrayLength; i++)
      {
       // Finds item and removes it
       if (onList[i] == objSelect)
       {
          onList.splice(i, 1);
          ///*/**/*/trace("Item Removed: " + onList[i]);
          trace("Array Updated: " + onList);
       }
      }

    }

    // function frameloop ------------------------------------------------------------------
    /*  function frameloop(e:Event)
      {
      }
    */

    // function sendPhp ------------------------------------------------------------------
     function sendPhp(e:MouseEvent):void
     {

      // send vars to php
      var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("write_xml.php"); // the php file to send data to
      var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(); // create an array of POST vars

      variables['bathLight'] = compTxt.text;
      variables['bathLight'] = bathLightTxt.text; 
      variables['computer'] = computerLightTxt.text; 
      variables['kitchenLight'] = kitchenLight.text;
      variables['livingLight'] = livingLightTxt.text; 
      variables['descLight'] = descLightTxt.text;
      variables['laundryLight'] = laundryLightTxt.text; 
      variables['oven'] = ovenTxt.text; 
      variables['tv'] = tvTxt.text;
      variables['washer'] = washerTxt.text;  

      request.data = variables; // send the vars to the data property of the requested url (our php file)
      request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; // use POST as the send method
      try
      {
       var sender:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
       sender.load(request); // load the php file and send it the variable data
       navigateToURL(new URLRequest("vars.xml"), '_blank'); //show me the xml
      } 
      catch (e:Error) 
      {
       trace(e); // trace error if there is a problem
      }
     }


     // function called when user clicks on update button-----------------------------------
     /*function updateStage():void
     {
     for (var i:int = 0; i<=onList.length;i++) { 
     addChild(onList[i]);
     }

     }*/


     } //end of class

    } // end of package
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be better off keeping track of the reference to your textboxes in order to populate them afterwards:

```
var textFields:Array = new Array();
textFields[0] = compTxt;
textFields[1] = bathLightTxt;
textFields[2] = computerLightTxt;
textFields[3] = kitchenLight;
textFields[4] = livingLightTxt;
textFields[5] = descLightTxt;
textFields[6] = laundryLightTxt;
textFields[3] = ovenTxt;
textFields[8] = tvTxt; 
textFields[9] = washerTxt;
```

I tried it out this way:

```
import fl.controls.*;
var textFields:Array = new Array(9);
textFields[0] = new TextInput();
textFields[1] = new TextInput();
textFields[2] = new TextInput();
textFields[3] = new TextInput();
textFields[4] = new TextInput();
textFields[5] = new TextInput();
textFields[6] = new TextInput();
textFields[7] = new TextInput();
textFields[8] = new TextInput();
textFields[9] = new TextInput();

var i:uint = 0;
for(i = 0; i < textFields.length; ++i){
   textFields[i].text = "Set text at " + i;
   trace(textFields[i].text);
}
```